# How can i use this code in PHP 5.2?

Tags: php, php-5.2

This is a part of SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php from spreadsheet-reader-master that I want to use on PHP 5.2.6 but it always gives an error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::add() in ..\spreadsheet-reader-master\SpreadsheetReader_XLSX.php on line 830 and it is not possible to upgrate my PHP version.

```
$Value = clone self::$BaseDate;
$Value -> add(new DateInterval('P'.$Days.'D'.($Seconds ? 'T'.$Seconds.'S' : '')));

if (!$this -> Options['ReturnDateTimeObjects'])
    {
        $Value = $Value -> format($Format['Code']);
    }
    else
    {
        // A DateTime object is returned
    }
```

Comment: _"it is not possible to upgrate my PHP version"_ Seriosly? PHP 5.2 was EOL'ed over 4 years ago, 5.3 was killed last year, and 5.4 support ends in little over a month. If you _really_ can't upgrade, change host

Comment: It's people running ancient versions of PHP that mean library writers can't improve their libraries... look to upgrade your version of PHP to something from this decade